# How to pick a specific array object in IonicFramework?

Tags: ionic-framework

output sample: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kETay.png)

In the furtherModules function, under the main module Environmental Compliance Management there is two sub modules which is Chemical Management and PPE Management, so when the user click Chemical Management it should go to a new page and when the user click PPE Management it should go to another page.I don't know how to do that. I really need help on this.

```html
home.html code:

<ion-content class="outer-content">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      {{content}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="content" color="dark">
        <ion-segment-button value="Environment Compliace Management">
          <ion-icon name="flask"></ion-icon>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="Health & Safety Management">
          <ion-icon name="medkit"></ion-icon>
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
      <ion-list style="margin: 0" inset>
        <button ion-item *ngFor="let sContent of getContentItems(content)" (click)="furtherModules()">
          <ion-icon item-start [name]="sContent.icon" color= "primary"></ion-icon>
          {{sContent.name}}
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

```js
home.ts code:


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {ModuleListPage} from '../module-list/module-list';
import { identifierName } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage{
  content="MODULES";
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}


  items: any = {
    'Environmental Compliance Management': [
      {
        name: 'Chemical Management',
        icon: 'nuclear',
      },

      {
        name: 'PPE Management',
        icon: 'man'
      }
    ],
    'Health & Safety Management': [
      {
        name: 'Emergency Incident Management',
        icon: 'alert'
      },
      {
        name: 'Machinery Management',
        icon: 'construct'
      },
      {
        name: 'Risk Management',
        icon: 'cog'
      }
    ]
  };
  getContentItems(type:any){
    return this.items[type];
  }
  furtherModules(){
  }
}
```

Comment: does your ts file getting error? try to log the value `item`

Comment: @nyx97 nope, my ts file not getting any error.

Comment: can you console log the `item` variable?

Comment: @nyx97 I am sorry but I could not be able to understand what you really mean, can you explain to me in detail?

Answer (score 1):

First need to identify which page are we directing to, for an example in my case i generate a dummy page which is 'MyAwesomePage' and 'MyAnotherAwesomePage' then in .ts file need to do something like this

```js
{
  name: 'Chemical Management',
  icon: 'nuclear',
  goTo: 'MyAwesomePage'
},

{
  name: 'PPE Management',
  icon: 'man',
  goTo: 'MyAnotherAwesomePage'
}


public furtherModules(sContent:any): void{
 // Validate here if sContent.goTo is a valid page
 this.navCtrl.push(sContent.goTo, {_sContent: sContent});
}
```

after that, in .html file need to do something like this

```html
<ion-list style="margin: 0" inset>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let sContent of getContentItems(content)" (click)="furtherModules(sContent)">
       <ion-icon item-start [name]="sContent.icon" color= "primary"></ion-icon>
          {{sContent.name}}
    </button>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just understand what do you want to achieve

1. You must create a page for both **Environment Compliace Management** and **Health & Safety Management** using cli below

`ionic g page Environment Compliace Management`
`ionic g page Health & Safety Management`

refer to this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/) for more details,better to read the documentation first.

2. Add your page to your `app.module.ts` refer to this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-create-generate-add-pages/) i dont need to explain it
3. third do something like below

In your html file put some input paramers to your furthermodules function

```
(click)="furtherModules(content)
```

In your ts file do something like below

```
furtherModules(type:any){
       if('Environment Compliace Management'){
          this.navCtrl.push(*name of your page to environment compliace management*)
       }
       else{
          this.navCtrl.push(*name of your page to Health & Safety Management*)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion,I really appreciate it. I have already created two pages. In my case what I want is that under the main module **Environmental Compliance Management** there is two sub modules which is **Chemical Management** and **PPE Management**, so when the user click Chemical Management it should go to a new page and when the user click PPE Management it should go to another page. This is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: can you show me some images what you want to achieve?

Comment: i suspect you want something like [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/) ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kETay.png
Please click this link to see the output, so when the user click the **Chemical Management** it should go to a new page.

Comment: @Raj refer to my `futherModules` function , disregard the if condition. Using `this.navCtrl.push(nameofyourpage)` command it will redirect to a new page, just insert if condition if you have some logical commands

Comment: still I could not be able to do. Thank you so much for your suggestion. it means a lot to me

Comment: @Raj do you have codes in your github about this? so that i can see

Comment: @Raj post your solution mate for someone who will read this thread in the future

Comment: posted buddy :)
Thank you for your suggestion :)